# What is the origin relatioinship between the Cursed Blood Clan and the Kyoukai no Kanata?

Tags: beyond-the-boundary

Watching the movie, it seems like there is some relationship between the Cursed Blood Clan (CBC) (Kuriyama's) and the Kyoukai no Kanana (KnK) Youmu's origin.

And I am not talking about the **romantic** relationsip between Mirai and Akihito. About the origins of them both.

It is shown that

> Akihito and Mirai's mothers were close enough that Kuriyama could ask to be reforged into a ring upon her death.

So, what is the rellationship?

> Was the CBC involved in creating KnK?